# Django NoReverseMatch using views parameter

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

i am doing a inventory app and i have included actions(CRUD) to perform on the saved items. However when a click on 'dispatch' i get this error, *NoReverseMatch at /inventory
Reverse for 'dispatch' with arguments '('hhe/ge/3.009/67-8',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['dispatch/(?P[^/]+)$']*  hhe/ge/3.009/67-8 is one of model_numbers.

**dispatch_view in views.py**

```
def dispatch_view(request,model_number):
    if request.method=='POST':

        dispatch_item=New_asset.objects.get(model_number=model_number)
        form= dispatch_form(request.POST,instance=dispatch_item)

        if form.is_valid():

                post = form.save(commit=False)

                post.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/inventory')

    else:
                form = dispatch_form()

    return render(request, 'dispatch.html', {'form': form,'dispatch_item':dispatch_item})
```

**url.py**
     
     `path('dispatch/<str:model_number>', views.dispatch_view,name='dispatch'),
     url(r'^inventory$', views.allassets,name='inventory'),`

**inventory.html**

```
    {% for asset in query %}
                              <tr class="clickable-row">
                                  <td>{{asset.asset_name}}</td>
                                  <td>{{asset.model_number}}</td>
                                  <td>{{asset.quantity_received}}</td>
                                  <td>{{asset.specification}}</td>
                                  <td>{{asset.supplied_by}}</td>
                                  <td>{{asset.department_assigned}}</td>
                                  <td>{{asset.date_received}}</td>
                                  <td><a href=" {%url 'dispatch' asset.model_number%}"><span 
                                                 class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" >Dispatch</span></a>
```

Thanks

Comment: post your models also

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the rep to comment, so this will have to be an answer.

Have you tried putting your app name infront of 'dispatch' like below?

```
href="{% url 'inventory_app_name:dispatch' asset.model_number %}"
```

Comment: have done so but am getting "app_name" is not a registered namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that model number is an Integer, try using the code below:

```
url(r'^ dispatch/(?P<model_number>\d+)/$', views.dispatch_view, name='dispatch'),
```

You can then access the model number in the kwargs as:

```
kwargs['model_number']
```

Comment: am still getting the same error. The model_number is str, the reason i used the str converter in url. This is what i think could be wrong: 1. the CRUD actions are on the inventory page/view but my arguments and url parameters are on the dispatch view and url. 2.The model_number is being passed ok but the inventory view/url has no way to get the parameters.   error again: **NoReverseMatch at /inventory
**  **Reverse for 'dispatch' with arguments '('hhe/ge/3.009/67-8',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['dispatch/(?P<model_number>[0-9]+)$']
**     i hope this helps

Comment: This is the error after i changed converter from int to str     ** NoReverseMatch at /inventory
Reverse for 'dispatch' with arguments '('hhe/ge/3.009/67-8',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['dispatch/(?P<model_number>[^/]+)$'] **